# CMake of google-cloud-cpp for speech fails

Tags: c++, linux, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-speech

I am trying to run quickstart file from speech:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp/tree/main/google/cloud/speech

I have installed all the dependencies but the cmake command fails for me with the following error :

```
-- Found RE2 via CMake.
CMake Error at /root/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:613 (_add_library):
  _add_library cannot create ALIAS target
  "google-cloud-cpp::experimental-speech" because target
  "google-cloud-cpp::speech" is IMPORTED.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /root/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/share/google_cloud_cpp_speech/google_cloud_cpp_speech-config.cmake:25 (add_library)
  /root/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:824 (_find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:21 (find_package)
```

The command used by me :

```
cmake -H. -B.build -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$HOME/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
```

I am not getting error while running the same command at the super folder.
Below is the output for command used at super folder level :

```
root@jioeva-cas-dev-2:~/google-cloud-cpp# cmake -H. -B.build -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$HOME/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
-- Doxygen generation only enabled for cmake 3.9 and higher
-- CURL linkage will be non-static
-- Doxygen generation only enabled for cmake 3.9 and higher
-- Doxygen generation only enabled for cmake 3.9 and higher
-- Doxygen generation only enabled for cmake 3.9 and higher
-- Doxygen generation only enabled for cmake 3.9 and higher
-- Doxygen generation only enabled for cmake 3.9 and higher
-- Doxygen generation only enabled for cmake 3.9 and higher
-- Doxygen generation only enabled for cmake 3.9 and higher
-- CURL linkage will be non-static
-- CURL linkage will be non-static
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /root/google-cloud-cpp/.build
```